# no video with support format and mime type found

Tags: 12.04

I have just install Ubuntu 12.04. When i used firefox to open [online videos](http://tv.zing.vn/video/Accel-World-Tap-3/IWZAOUZD.html), it didn't open.

The error show that no video with support format and mime type found.

Who met this errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested the link that you provided in your question and it works for me. After a quick check it seems that you just need to install a Flash player to watch such videos.

Open the Software Center and install `flashplugin-installer`.

[image]